# Showing theres no metric wrt a topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image: c enter image description here]

I have a homework problem that I have no clue how to approach and answer. My topology is kind of weak not entirely sure that I understand the question.

**My attempt:**

i) If  $V_{1}$ is a sequence of neighborhoods of the zero function then there is a function say $h_{1} \in C[0,1] $ such that $h_{1} (x) = 1 $ where $h \in V$ [ not entirely sure why this is true but a friend told me this] . Now if we let sequence of neighbourhoods $ V_{1} , V_{2} , .. V_{n} $ to contain functions $h_{1} , h_{2} ... h_{n} $ respectively such that all $h_n(x) = 1$. Is this correct?

ii) How do I go about showing that no metric exist?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given doesn't work, as it's not clear what the point $x$ or the functions $h_1, \ldots, h_n$ are. You don't seem to have constructed anything here.

Note that each neighbourhood only controls the functions within it at a *single point*. If we consider, for example, $V_{1, (3,4)}$, the functions in this neighbourhood are precisely the continuous functions $f : [0, 1] \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $3 < f(1) < 4$. This poses no restriction on $f(x)$ for any $x \neq 1$; basically I can pick any $x \neq 1$ and any $y \in \Bbb{R}$, and find a function in $V_{1, (3,4)}$ such that $f(x) = y$.

We have a sequence of neighbourhoods $V_n$. Each of these neighbourhoods must contain a sub-basic neighbourhood $V_{x_n, U_n}$, by definition of the topology. Now, there are only countably many points in the sequence $(x_n)$, and $[0, 1]$ is uncountable, so there must be a point $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $x \neq x_n$ for all $n$. By the above argument, we can find a continuous function $h_n$ in each $V_n$ so that $h_n(x) = 1$, simply because $x \neq x_n$ for all $n$ (for example, take the equation for the line between points $(x, 1)$ and $(x_n, u_n)$, where $u_n$ is some point - your choice - in $U_n$).

For the second part, we need to observe a property of metric spaces that this topological space does not possess, probably to do with the previous part. In this case, it looks like the property of first countability might be an issue (why else would we consider a sequence of neighbourhoods of a single point?). Metric spaces have first countability because of the local basis $B_{1/n}(x)$ of open balls around each point $p$, so let's start by assuming a metric does exist, and applying the previous part to the sequence of open sets $B_{1/n}(0)$ for $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

By the previous part, there exists some $x \in [0, 1]$ and functions $h_n$ such that $h_n \in B_{1/n}(0)$ and $h_n(x) = 1$. In particular, note that $d(h_n, 0) < 1/n$ for all $n$, hence $h_n \to 0$.

Now, look at a neighbourhood $V = V_{x, (-1, 1)}$ of the $0$ function, and note that $h_n \notin V$ for any $n$. This contradicts $h_n \to 0$. Thus, by contradiction, no metric can exist for this topology.

Comment: My topology is bad and I appreciate the detail in your the answer I think Im slowly understanding the question, there was actually two more questions piror to this which i thought I did correct but reading through realised I lacked understanding and my answers may not be correct. 1) If V is a neighbourhood of the constant zero function  ,show that there are a finite set of points $x_{1}, .. x_{n} \in [0,1]$ such that V contains functions g which satisfy $g(x_{1}) , .. g(x_{n}) =0$ 2) Now let $x \in [0,1] \setminus \{ x_{1} , ...x_{n} \}$ show that there is a function $h \in V $ where h(x) =1

Comment: i)if V is a neighbourhood of the constant zero function does it contains functions that essentially evaluate to 0? So for example take  $V_{x,0}$ , the functions in here are functions such that f(x) =0 for $x ∈ [0,1]$ or would it have to be a set $V_{x,(-1,1)}? $ Such that $-1<f(x) <1$.  So there exist finitely many points x such that f(x) = 0.ii) From your argument you above since there aren’t any restrictions on f(x) as long as $x ≠ x_{1} , .... x_{n} $ I could just pick any $x \in [0,1] \setminus \{ x_{1} , ...x_{n} \}$ and y to be 1 and find a function h that is in V such that h(x)=1?

Comment: Before I address your questions, I should tell you that there is an error in my proof! Neighbourhoods may not necessarily contain sub-basic neighbourhoods, but they may contain a finite intersection of sub-basic neighbourhoods. So, for each neighbourhood $V_n$, there will not always be a single point that is forced to belong to an interval, but finitely many points, restricted to each their own interval. This isn't an obstacle; we just take $x$ to not be equal to any of these points for any of the countably many neighbourhoods. The union of all these points is still countable.

Comment: The set $V_{x, 0}$ (or more precisely, $V_{x, \{0\}}$) is not a neighbourhood of any point. To be a neighbourhood in this topology, you *must* have $U$ be open in $V_{x, U}$. You cannot force every $g$ in your neighbourhood to satisfy $g(x_1) = \ldots = g(x_n) = 0$. The question asks you to show that, given any neighbourhood of the $0$ function, you can find these finitely many points $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ so that for any function $g$ with $g(x_1) = \ldots = g(x_n) = 0$, you necessarily have $g \in V$. That is, the value at every other point does not affect membership in $V$.

Comment: @Swag34214 From my argument above, you need to choose $x \in [0, 1]$ in such a way that it doesn't equal any of the finitely many points corresponding to each $V_n$. Each $V_n$ is a neighbourhood, and there are the finitely many points corresponding to each one as guaranteed by question 1. If you take the (countable) union of all these finite sets, the result is still countable, and thus not equal to $[0, 1]$. Just pick $x$ to be any number in the (non-empty) complement of this countable set.

Comment: I understand most of what you are saying i think, so for each neighbourhood $V_{n}$ there are finitely many points that are restricted to the interval. So I could just choose an $x$ that isnt the same as any of the finite points( which is guarenteed because [0,1] is uncountable while union of finite sets are countable). So for that choosen value of $x$ I could set y to be 1? and hence h(x) =1? Is this how I would go about showing a function h(x)=1 exist around the neighbourhood of the constant zero function? I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "you necessarily have $g  \in V$".

Comment: I guess some of my confusion now is to why there are 'finitely many points' that satisfy g such that $g(x_{1}) = ... g(x_{n}) = 0 $ for a neighbourhood around the constant zero function. Doesnt the constant zero function have infinitely many points $x \in [0,1] $ such that f(x) = 0? Why/how does a function exist around the neighbourhood of the constant zero function where finite points satisify it? Is it because the only function that contains infinitely many points would be the constant zero and any other function around the neighbouhood must have finite points to 0? Thanks much appreciated

Comment: @Swag34214 There's a lot of questions that are really tricky to answer by comments. I think you should ask a separate question. Link back to this question, and let me know by comments so I can give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set $Y=\Bbb R^{[0,1]}$ of all functions from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R,$ which can be considered to be the product of $2^{\aleph_0}$ copies of $\Bbb R,$ although we use $[0,1]$ for the index of the product.  A base $B$ for the (Tychonoff ) product topology on $Y$ is the set of all  $\prod_{x\in [0,1]}A_x$ such that

$(i). \{x:A_x\ne \Bbb R\}$ is finite, and

$(ii).$ If $A_x\ne \Bbb R$ then $A_x$ is a bounded open real interval.

Now $S$ is a sub-base for $\tau.$ The set $T$ of all $\cap W,$ over all $finite$ $W\subset S,$ is a base for $\tau.$ And $$T=\{b\cap C[0,1]: b\in B\}.$$ So $X$ with the topology $\tau$ is a sub-space of $Y$ with the Tychonoff product topology on $Y.$

Q i). Let $\{V_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be a sequence of nbhds of $any$ $f\in X.$ For each $n\in \Bbb N$ there exists $V'_n\in B$ such that $f\in V'_n\cap X\subset V_n.$

Let $V'_n=X\cap \prod_{x\in [0,1]}A_{x,n}$ where $\prod_{x\in [0,1]}A_{n,x}\in B.$

Let $C_n=\{x\in [0,1]: A_{x,n}\ne \Bbb R\}.$

Each $C_n$ is finite so $[0,1]\ne \cup_{n\in \Bbb N}C_n.$ So let $x_0 \in [0,1]\setminus \cup_{n\in \Bbb N}C_n.$

Now for each $n$, since $C_n$ is finite, and $x_0\not \in C_n ,$  and $A_{x_0,n}=\Bbb R,$ there exists $h_n\in X $ such that $h_n(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in C_n$ and $h_n(x_0)=1+f(x_0).$

So for all $n\in \Bbb N$ we have $h_n\in V_n$ and $h_n(x_0)=1+f(x_0).$

Q ii). Suppose the $\tau$ topology is metrizable. Then it is first-countable: For every $f\in X$ there exists a countable set $\{V_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ of nbhds of $f$ such that if $V$ is any nbhd of $f$ then there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $V_n\subset V.$

But from Q i), consider the nbhd $V=C[0,1]\cap \prod_{x\in [0,1]}A'_x$ where $A'_x=\Bbb R$ if $x\ne x_0$ and $A'_{x_0}= (f(x_0)-1/2,\, f(x_0)+1/2)\,).$  For every $n\in \Bbb N$ we have $h_n\in V_n\setminus V$ so $V_n\not \subset V.$

Remark. In Q ii), if $d$ is a metric for a space $X$ and $f\in X$ we can let $\{V_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be the set $\{B_d(f,1/n):n\in \Bbb N\}$ of open balls.

Answer (score 0):

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3294230/4280) you ask for the fact that if $V$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ (the function in $C([0,1])$) there is a finite set $F(V)$ such that if $f$ is $0$ on all points of $F(V)$ then $f \in V$. This is shown there in my answer (part 1).

So find such a finite set $F(V_n)$ for each $V_n$ when we are given the sequence $(V_n)$ of open neighbourhoods of $0$.

Then we can find $x \in [0,1]$ and such that $x \notin F(V_n)$ for every $n$. The union of the $F(V_n)$ is countable and $[0,1]$ is uncountable.

Now apply fact 2 from the above question for each $n$ and $V_n$: We know $x \notin F(V_n)$, so there is a function $h_n \in V$ with $h_n(x)=1$ (we can make a piecewise linear function that is $0$ on the finite set $F(V_n)$, ensuring $h_n \in V_n$, and $1$ on $x$ very easily).

So i) is a straightforward application of the linked question using only that $[0,1]$ is uncountable as an extra step.

Note that $h_n \not\to 0$ because it does not converge pointwise at $x$, or note that $V_{1,(-\frac12,\frac12)}$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ that misses all $h_n$.

Now (ii) follows from the following observation which holds in any metric space $(X,d)$:

> For every $x \in X$ there is a sequence of neighbourhoods $(V_n(x))$ of $x$, such that if we pick any $x_n \in V_n(x)$, then $x_n \to x$.

Proof: take $V_n = B(x, \frac1n)$ and check the easy details.

Now we have just shown under (i) that

> For $X = C([0,1])$ and $x=0$, whatever sequence of neighbourhoods $(V_n)$ we choose of $0$, there always is a choice $h_n \in V_n$ such that $h_n \not \to 0$.

This shows that $C([0,1])$ is topologically different in an essential way from any metric space. So it's not metrisable. The point $0$ is coincidental BTW, this could be done for any function $f \in C[0,1])$, as the space is homogeneous.